# Ruby on Rails conditional stylesheets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stylesheet

I was wondering if Ruby on Rails had a elegant way of displaying conditional stylesheets or do I need to use the default

```
    <!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie7.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's really no need for such a thing in Rails. It is really simple.

But if you want to make it look better, you might consider [Haml](http://haml-lang.com) view engine.

It allows you to do this:

```
/[if IE 7]
  = stylesheet_link_tag 'ie7', :media => 'screen'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have no other choice if you are using erb.